# How to set ssh config for 2 different gitlab accounts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

I am setting up my ssh config for 2 different accounts in gitlab.

```
Host gitlab.com-roulette
    HostName gitlab.com
    User norayr.ghukasian
    IdentityFile /home/norayr_ghukasyan/.ssh/id_ed25519_roulette

Host gitlab.com-devlix
    HostName gitlab.com
    User norayr.ghukasyan
    IdentityFile /home/norayr_ghukasyan/.ssh/id_ed25519_devlix
```

I am getting a `Permission denied` error.
The strange thing for me is that the first one is working fine, therefore I think there is some tiny issue in my config that I am not aware of. I guess when the user or the server tries to connect, ssh automatically matches the first config with matched `HostName`.
How do I set up it properly to work for both of the accounts?

P.S. The `User`s are different - `norayr.ghukasian` and `norayr.ghukasyan`.

Comment: What's odd to me is that usually the `User` is always `git`?  I'm kind of surprised either of these work. In any case, this is covered in [use different accounts on a single gitlab instance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#use-different-accounts-on-a-single-gitlab-instance). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [Use difference accounts on a single GitLab instance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#use-different-accounts-on-a-single-gitlab-instance) you would setup your configuration like so:

```
Host norayr.ghukasian.gitlab.com
  Hostname gitlab.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/norayr_ghukasyan/.ssh/id_ed25519_roulette

Host norayr.ghukasyan.gitlab.com
  Hostname gitlab.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/norayr_ghukasyan/.ssh/id_ed25519_devlix
```

Then to clone a repo as `norayr.ghukasian` user:

```
git clone git@norayr.ghukasian.gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab.git
```

Using the username as the alias is not absolutely necessary. You can use a different alias if you wish and set it in the `Host` section of your ssh config.

Key takeaways:

1. The only thing that you need to tell GitLab who you are is the `IdentityFile`.
2. You can direct git/ssh to use a specific identity file by the alias you use for the host configured in the ssh config.

Comment: Okay , that did the trick, thanks a lot. But I can't get one thing.I have updated my remote url to include the Host alias as per gitlab docs. How does it work ? How does the Host alias related to git remote url ?

Comment: Through the ssh config on the `Host` line. When ssh goes to resolve the remote, the ssh config tells it that the real hostname is `gitlab.com` (and to use the other associated settings for that host). Hope that helps @NorayrGhukasyan